# Selected image in recyclerview is get unselected upon scroll

Tags: android

In my recyclerview has one imageview and textview. I'm changing image of ImageView onn `onClickListener`. Now the problem is if i click on image of position 3 and scroll down... image of position 8 is also changed and again if i scroll up...image of position 2 is changed.

```
public class PortraitListviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PortraitListviewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
static    List<PortraitParentListAdapterBean> list;
static List<String> selectedPosition ;

public PortraitListviewAdapter(Context context, List<PortraitParentListAdapterBean> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    selectedPosition = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.listview_parent_portrait, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    PortraitParentListAdapterBean portBean = list.get(position);
    Log.i("pos",position+"");
    holder.parentHeading.setText(portBean.getHeading());
    if (selectedPosition.contains(list.get(position).getHeading())){
        holder.parentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView parentHeading;
    protected ImageView parentImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        parentHeading = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_heading);
        parentImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectedPosition.add(list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getHeading());
                parentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

the above code is my implementation for recyclerview adapter. please help to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

change

```
if (selectedPosition.contains(list.get(position).getHeading())){
        holder.parentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
}
```

with

```
if (selectedPosition.contains(list.get(position).getHeading())){
        holder.parentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
} else {
        holder.parentImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_default_drawable);
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

When you scroll your RecyclerView the system doesn't recreate always your ViewHolder but reuse one you previously scrolled that is no longer visible, so you need to reset your standard values in order to avoid showing wrong values.